# show.html.erb page for viewing by users other than current_user

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to create the `user/show.html.erb` page that another user can view, which renders all of the viewed user's information.  This includes a feed of objects called cars.  I cannot get the feed to render correctly.

**users/show.html.erb**

```
<div>
  <aside class="col-md-4">
    <div>
      <h1>My Profile</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="hero-unit user_info">
      <h1><%= @user.name %></h1>
      <h2><%= pluralize(@user.cars.count, "Car") %></h2>
    </div>
  </aside>

  <div class="col-md-8">
    <h1>My Cars</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <div id="car_feed">
        <ul class="cars">
          <%= render @feed_items %>  //problem point
        </ul>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It's the render @feed_items part that is giving me trouble.  Feed is defined in `user.rb`:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cars
  attr_accessor :remember_token
  before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
  validates :name,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                    format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  has_secure_password
  validates :phone, presence:true
  validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }, allow_blank: true

.
.
.

  def feed
    Car.where("user_id = ?", id)
  end
end
```

And feed items in the static pages controller

class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController

```
  def home
    if logged_in?
      @car = current_user.cars.build
      @feed_items = current_user.feed.paginate(page: params[:page])
    end
  end
end
```

There are two classes of users, and I need for the other class "shop" to be able to view this page and all of the objects in the feed that belong to the user on the show.html.erb page.

I'm not getting error messages, but just the literal code is being despayed on the page.How can I do this?

[image]

**users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :admin_user,     only: :destroy

    def index
      @users = User.all
    end

    def show
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    def new
      @user = User.new
    end

    def create
      @user = User.new(user_params)
      if @user.save
        log_in @user
        flash[:success] = "Thank you for signing up, welcome to ensage!"
        redirect_to root_path
      else
        render 'new'
      end
    end

    def edit
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    def update
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
        flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
        redirect_to @user
      else
          render 'edit'
      end
    end

    def destroy
      User.find(params[:id]).destroy
      flash[:success] = "User deleted"
      redirect_to users_url
    end

    private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :phone, :password,
                                   :password_confirmation)
    end

    def correct_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user?(@user)
    end

    def admin_user
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.admin?
    end
end
```

Comment: What do you mean by "literal code"? Could attach screenshot?

Comment: Added up top. that code is definitely not supposed to work, need to fill in

Comment: I'm afraid it can't work. You have provided template of `users/show.html.erb`, and what is in your screenshot just confirms, that you are executing action of `users#show`.

On the other hand, you have provided example of your code from your `StaticController`, `home` action, which is expected to populate `@feed_items`.

Could you provide code of your `UsersController`?

Comment: @PawełDawczak I provided the UsersController.  I need to know how users#show can show a user profile page to a shop or user that is logged in.

Answer (score 0):

You will need something like this:

**users/show.html.erb**

```
<ul class="cars">
    <% @feed_itmes.each do |feed_items| %>
         <li><%= feed_items %></li>  
    <% end %>
</ul>
```

Also, place your `@feed_items` variable in your show method in the users controller:

```
def show
  @feed_items = current_user.feed.paginate(page: params[:page])
end
```

Comment: This gave me the error `undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: Sorry, @VirgeAssault  I have added a piece of code to my answer, if that doesn't work I let me know and I will delete my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Because of information you provided in your last comment, it's more clear what the problem is. To make your current code to work, try adding the line in your `UsersController#show`:

```
@feed_items = @user.feed.paginate(page: params[:page])
```

So your action looks like this:

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @feed_items = @user.feed.paginate(page: params[:page])
end
```

Hope it makes your template to work!